# Can I add a texture to a svg rectangle face and then change the perspective

Tags: svg

Is it possible to have a jpg image set as the face or texture to a polygon in an svg and then tilt that face backwards. so it goes from

[image]

To:

[image]

If not how can I achieve this effect with using SVG.

Comment: set the jpg as a pattern, use a css 3d transform for perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do CSS 3D transforms on SVG child elements like `<polygon>`.  However you can do 3D transforms on the SVG as a whole - the same as you would any HTML element.  However that means the whole SVG has the same perspective transform. You would need multiple SVGs to draw a 3D solid.  For example, six SVGs for a cube.